# SVD testing non zero values

Tags: floating-point, svd, inverse

I was looking at the matlab function pinv.m for the compuation of the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). The code uses the singular values decomposition.
$$
A = U D V
$$
When looking for non-zero diagonal elements it sets a threshold using the formula:
$$max(n,m) * eps(d_{max}) $$
where $n$ is number of rows $m$ number of columns of $A$, $eps$ is the machine precision and $d_{max}$ is the biggest singular values. Apparently this is the standard way to [do it](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-be-the-criteria-for-accepting-rejecting-singular-values).
However, I cannot easily find the explanation for such formula.
Could somebody provide it?
Also, is it a strict upper bound of the floating point error or some probabilistic consideration are taken into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition comes from considering how wrong your singular values could be given a matrix $A \approx A + \delta A$. I think this ultimately goes back to Golub (or even before). I managed to hunt down a proper proof of an actual SVD algorithm from [Ipsen](https://ipsen.math.ncsu.edu/ps/tr97-24.ps) (Sec. 4, pg 28). This result ultimately follows from a careful round-off error analysis: the $\text{max}(m,n) \epsilon$ term comes from the accumulation of machine epsilon-scale errors at most either $m$ or $n$ times, whichever is larger, and the largest singular value is the 2-norm of $A$.

Comment: Many thanks, I am going trough the proof, so is it a strict upper bound?

Comment: In this case, yes, but this is for the Jacobi method. I know that this heuristic is used broadly, going back many decades. I am not sure if it is a hard upper bound in all such cases. However, flirting with the bound is probably not a good idea _in practice_.